# Automapper - Create a simple mapping between two classes AND use custom converters for specific types

Tags: c#, automapper, typeconverter

I want to map two classes with Automapper, but I want to use custom converters for **specific property types** in the destination, **NOT specific members**.

Simple Example:

```cs
public class Source
{
    public string SomeString {get;set;}  = "TEST";

    public string SomeNullableInt {get;set;}  = "10";

    public string AnotherNullableInt {get;set;}  = "This is not an integer";

    public string SomeDate {get;set;}  = "20220202";
}
```

```cs
public class Destination
{
    public string SomeString {get;set;};

    public int? SomeNullableInt {get;set;};

    public int? AnotherNullableInt {get;set;};

    public DateTime SomeDate {get;set;};
}
```

```cs
public class NullableIntTypeConverter : ITypeConverter<string, int?>
{
    public int? Convert(string source, int? destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        // return My Custom Logic here.
    }
}
```

```cs
public class DateTimeTypeConverter : ITypeConverter<string, DateTime>
{
    public DateTime Convert(string source, DateTime destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        // return My Custom Logic here.
    }
}
```

```cs
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>());
// Dear Automapper, please use my custom ITypeConverters, whenever I map Source and Destination....(I tried for hours on this one, but I failed)
```

**My question**: How do I tell Automapper, to **always** use my custom ITypeConverters for **ANY** int? and DateTime in Destination, whenever I map Source and Destination? (without using "member mapping"....)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `ConvertUsing()` to specify the converter you want to use for mapping one type to another. See the examples from [Custom Type Converters](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-type-converters.html):

> ```
> var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
>   cfg.CreateMap<string, int>().ConvertUsing(s => Convert.ToInt32(s));
>   cfg.CreateMap<string, DateTime>().ConvertUsing(new DateTimeTypeConverter());
>   cfg.CreateMap<string, Type>().ConvertUsing<TypeTypeConverter>();
>   cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>();
> });
> ```

In your case you can register the converter as follow:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>();
    cfg.CreateMap<string, int?>().ConvertUsing<NullableIntTypeConverter>();
    cfg.CreateMap<string, DateTime>().ConvertUsing<DateTimeTypeConverter>();
});
```

Comment: Thank you Progman for your help. I didn't had the time to come back and say thank you immediatley. My case was a bit more complex, but yes, basically it was just like the documentation.